# mdb tools sql query table name space separated

Tags: c, eclipse, mdbtools

I'm trying to make an ODBC query for my .mdb database. I'm using mdbtools driver. The code is written in C using Eclipse. The only problem is that when I write for example:

> "SELECT 'last week' FROM MyTable GROUP"

it doesn't work cause it cannot recognize the space separator from the table field. I have no idea about the SQL syntax used by MDB tools driver.

MyTable fields are:

```
ID   jobs  last week  
1     ..      ...  
2  
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To delimit names with spaces in them you need to use square brackets.

```
"SELECT [last week] FROM MyTable GROUP"
```

This also works for table names.